# S is a subgroup generated by U(a subset)

Tags: group-theory

I have given any group G and a subset U. Let S be the smallest subgroup of G which contains U. I have to prove there exists such a subgroup S in G.
But i don't know how to prove it. Please help me anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
Let $S$ to be intersection of all subgroup which contains $U$.
Prove the following:
(i)$S$ is a subgroup.
(ii)If $T$ is a subgroup of $G$ which contains $U$, then $S\subseteq T$

Comment: (i) $S$ is a subgroup which contains $U$.

Comment: thanks a lot.....its very helpful...Alan Wang

Answer (score 0):

Consider the set $H$ of all words in $U\cup U^{-1}$. Follow this roadmap:

- $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.
- $H$ contains $U$.
- If $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ which contains $U$, then $K$ contains $H$.

Comment: Yah I got it. Thanks a lot. lhf